# Paginate 20,000 API results without database

Tags: php, pagination

I access a SOAP webservice which can return results, for example, of 20000 ID's in array form.

I need to then use the same webservice to get more information about each of those 20,000 ID's but making 20,000 API requests is obviously not an option.

The API is limited as you can see. No pagination and no way to get the required additional data in the initial pull.

I also have no database access to store and loop through.

Any other options to paginate this data outside of a massive timeout value that I might have overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No database? Surely you have something.. access the filesystem and serialize the results there.

Answer (score 1):

How often does the data change? You might have to do the 20k API calls, but you don't want to do so on every request. Maybe you can setup a cronjob which caches the data on your server, for example every hour or every day, depending on how often the data changes.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery paginator plugin can help DAN, **http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html**

Comment: Not in this instance - it needs the raw data already in order to paginate. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this http://lotsofcode.com/php/php-array-pagination.htm

Comment: Answers should be more than just links. It should include a summary of the linked content so that if (when) the link is broken the answer is still of some use.

Comment: This link is no longer valid.